# How to query data in `ranges` between range where ranges are saved in DB in single column separated by `-`?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have following table `ranges`

```
id title range 
1  ABC   0-500
2  PQR   501-600
3  XYZ   601-700
```

PHP Code

```
$range_input = "0-550";
$data = DB::select("Select * from ranges where range between $range_input");
```

Expected output:
I expect `id 1 and 2` in results between 0-550.

Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The design of your table is poor, and the lower and upper bounds of the range should be stored in separate columns (more on this later).  If are really stuck with the current design, you could use `SUBSTRING_INDEX` to separate the lower and upper bounds:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM ranges
WHERE ? < SUBSTRING_INDEX(`range`, '-', -1) AND
      ? > SUBSTRING_INDEX(`range`, '-', 1)
```

To the `?` placeholders, you may bind the range values for which you are searching, e.g. `0` and `550`

### Demo

Regarding your current design, it would be much better to store the lower and upper values of the range separately, that is, use this version of the table:

```
id title lower upper
1  ABC   0     500
2  PQR   501   600
3  XYZ   601   700
```

Now you only need the following simplified query:

```
SELECT *
FROM ranges
WHERE 0 < upper AND 550 > lower;
```

Comment: Don't think your query is quite right since the input is of the form `<lower>-<upper>` so you'd need to split that out, giving you something like: `SELECT * FROM ranges WHERE ? >= SUBSTRING_INDEX('range', '-', 1) AND ? <= SUBSTRING_INDEX('range', '-', -1);`

Comment: @Matt Not sure what you are asking here, since the query in your comment is logically equivalent to my answer.  `col BETWEEN x AND y` means the same thing as `col >= x AND col <= y`

Comment: Right but the given input is something like `0-500` so this query `SELECT * FROM ranges WHERE '0-500' BETWEEN SUBSTRING_INDEX('range', '-', 1) AND ? <= SUBSTRING_INDEX('range', '-', -1);` surely wouldn't work? Your demo returns 1 result while op expects 2 results for `$range_input = '0-550';`

Comment: @Matt Apologies, and you have read the question correctly.  It is the overlapping range problem in disguise.  I have updated my answer to reflect this.